# R:purrr Understanding purrr extraction functions

Tags: r, iteration, nested-lists, purrr, extract

Here is a simple nested list with three levels, the ob level, each of which contains two v-level lists; the v level, which contains either one or two s-level objects, and the s level, each of which contains a character vector.

```
test_lst <- list(ob1 = list(v1 = list(s1 = "X", s2 = paste0("A", 1:3)), v2 =  paste0("A", 4:8)), 
                 ob2 = list(v1 = list(s1 = "X", s2 = paste0("A", 9:11)), v2 =  paste0("A", 12:16)))
```

I am trying to understand how to access various levels of this list using purrr's map functions for extraction by name.

The help file on extraction provides an example using extraction by name of a list with no names at the top level. In this example the extraction function skips the  top level and uses the names to find elements at the second level.

```
l1 <- list(list(a = 1L), list(a = NULL, b = 2L), list(b = 3L))
l1 %>% map("a", .default = "???")
```

A second example has no names and is indexed positionally. Again, however, the positions are positions within each top-level element of the list.

```
l2 <- list(
 list(num = 1:3,     letters[1:3]),
 list(num = 101:103, letters[4:6]),
 list()
)
l2 %>% map(c(2, 2))
```

In the first example above, suppose the top level were named. What happens?

```
l1 <- list(one = list(a = 1L), two = list(a = NULL, b = 2L), three = list(b = 3L))
l1 %>% map("a", .default = "???")
```

The result is unchanged. 
So I expect the result from

```
map(test_lst, c("v1", "s2"))
```

to likewise skip the top-level names and return the equivalent of

```
lapply(c("ob1", "ob2"), function(X)test_lst[[X]][["v1"]][["s2"]])

[[1]]
[1] "A1" "A2" "A3"

[[2]]
[1] "A9"  "A10" "A11
```

But that is not what happens. Instead,

```
find_vars <- function(meta){
map_chr(meta, c("v1", "s2")) -> var_vecs
var_vecs
}

find_vars(meta = test_lst)
```

yields the following error:

```
 Error: Result 1 must be a single string, not a character vector of length 3
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace 
7. stop(cnd) 
6. abort(message, x = x, expected = expected, actual = actual, what = what, 
    arg = arg, ..., .subclass = c(.subclass, "purrr_error_bad_type")) 
5. stop_bad_type(x, expected, actual = actual, what = what, arg = arg, 
    recycle = recycle, message = message, .subclass = c(.subclass, 
        "purrr_error_bad_vector")) 
4. stop_bad_vector(x, expected_ptype, expected_length, what = what, 
    arg = arg, index = index, ..., recycle = recycle, message = message, 
    .subclass = c(.subclass, "purrr_error_bad_element_vector")) 
3. purrr:::stop_bad_element_vector(c("A1", "A2", "A3"), 1, character(0), 
    1, what = "Result", arg = NULL, recycle = FALSE) 
2. map_chr(meta, c("v1", "s2")) 
1. find_vars(meta = test_lst) 

> rlang::last_error()
<error>
message: Result 1 must be a single string, not a character vector of length 3
class:   `purrr_error_bad_element_vector`
backtrace:
 1. global::find_vars(meta = test_lst)
 3. purrr:::stop_bad_element_vector(...)
 4. purrr:::stop_bad_vector(...)
 5. purrr:::stop_bad_type(...)
Call `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full backtrace
> rlang::last_trace()
    x
 1. +-global::find_vars(meta = test_lst)
 2. | \-purrr::map_chr(meta, c("v1", "s2"))
 3. \-purrr:::stop_bad_element_vector(...)
 4.   \-purrr:::stop_bad_vector(...)
 5.     \-purrr:::stop_bad_type(...)
```

I would like to understand:

- why I get an error;
- what this particular error means: and
- how I could get a  result similar to the `lapply` results above using
  `purrr`.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to extract, then use `pluck`

```
pluck(test_lst, c("v1", "s2"))
```

---

Regarding the `error`, the `map_chr` expects to return a character `vector` based on the documentation

> map_lgl(), map_int(), map_dbl() and map_chr() each return an atomic vector of the indicated type (or die trying).

but the output here is a `list.  Consider the following example

```
map(test_lst, c("v1", "s2")) %>%
           map_chr(toString)
#         ob1            ob2 
#"A1, A2, A3" "A9, A10, A11"
```

After extracting the components as a `list`, we `paste` the elements to a single string within `map_chr` and it now flattens it to a `vector`.  But, if the intention is to return everything as a `vector`, it wouldn't allow

```
map(test_lst, c("v1", "s2")) %>% 
        map_chr(I)
```

> Error: Result 1 must be a single string, not a vector of class `AsIs`
>   and of length 3 Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace